# Movemouserelative to point A - point B

Tags: lua

I'm having trouble getting the movemouserelative to work smoothly from Fx,Fy to Hx,Hy

```
local x1 = 0
local y1 = 0
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    Fx, Fy = 41220, 36442
    Hx, Hy = 39205, 44459

    while x1 ~= Hx or y1 ~= Hy  do
        for i = 0 do 2015
            x1 = Fx - 1
            y1 = Fy + 4 --i got the 4 from subtracting lower fx and hx divide by 2015
            MoveMouseRelative(x1, y1) 
            Sleep(1000)
        end
    end
end
```

I'm at lost on what to put into the while statement it keeps giving me an error.

Comment: you should share the actual error message. "an error" is not very helpful

Comment: `MoveMouseRelative` accepts distance in pixels for relative move.  You have passed absolute coordinates in non-pixel units.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i = 0 do 2015
  x1 = Fx - 1
  y1 = Fy + 4 --i got the 4 from subtracting lower fx and hx divide by 2015
  MoveMouseRelative(x1, y1) 
  Sleep(1000)
end
```

This is incorrect. The syntax of a numerical for loop is:

```
stat ::= for Name ‘=’ exp ‘,’ exp [‘,’ exp] do block end
```

Note that of the three control expressions `initial value`, `limit` and `step`, only the third expression `step` is optional (see the square brackets).

In your code you failed to provide a limit.

Also you may not just have  a number in your code like the `2015` that comes after your `do`. This is also a syntax error.

Please read the Lua manual. https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.5

Further your code doesn't achieve anything useful.

You just assign the same constants over and over in your loop. As x1 and y1 never change and your condition will always be met your while loop will run forever. Causing a relative mouse movement of (41219; 36446) every second which is utter nonsense.

I suggest you start with pen and paper. Think about your problem. Make sure your actions make sense. Then implement it in Lua referring to the Lua manual.